# Локальная html страница со стилями и скриптами

Tags: javascript, html

> Есть приложение, которое производит анализ неких данных и генерирует
>   несколько видов отчетов, в т.ч. и html.
>
> На многих производственных машинах закрыт доступ к интернету. Поэтому
>   необходимо, чтоб все ресурсы для построения странички были локальными.
>   Сейчас реализовано все стандартным образом - html, и отдельно .js .css
>   и .js(с jquery). Ресурсы хранятся в папке проекта и естественно
>   пользователь не знает о них.

**Проблема в том**, что, когда пользователь копирует отчет (html) он получает голую страницу без стилей и js

**Нужно**, чтоб скопированная страница открывалась нормально.

> Известное мне решение - это скомпоновать страницу со встроенными
>   стилями через `<style></style>` и скриптами в соответствующем теге, а
>   картинки перегнать в base64. Остается вопрос - как в html встроить
>   полностью jquery

Answer (score 5):

Так-же как вы вставили все остальное:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // содержание jquery.min.js
</script>
```